# Prove that $0 < 1$. Prove that $ab = 0 \implies a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Proof: There exists $a = 0$ (For every $b$, an element of the set of positive numbers, such that: $b > a$)

$$a + b > 0 \implies b > 0 \implies a < b.$$

Thus, we have shown that $0 < b$ for every $b$ that is an element of the set of positive numbers. Now, we want to show that $ab = 0 \implies a = 0$ or $b = 0$.

If $a*b = 0$,

- $(a*b)/b \implies a = 0$
- $(a*b)/a \implies b = 0$

Therefore, $ab = 0 \implies a = 0$ or $b = 0$. QED.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are we working in $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ ? I don't like using division here, can you avoid it?

Comment: The problem did not specify. Is division not good since a or b can be 0 and thus the operation would be undefined?

Comment: That's one issue for sure, but also division is not closed on the integers. If you're trying to prove low-level stuff like this, my preference would be to use the simplest tools feasible.

Comment: So I should try to prove this with addition and additive inverses?

Comment: Well... you could use some multiplicative properties too, like distribution. I'm thinking you can aim for $((ab=0) \land (b>0)) \implies a=0$ . Do you have any special properties defined for 1?

Comment: I tried If a*b = 0, then (a+0)*b = a*b + 0*b = 0. This implies either a or b must be zero. Does this work?

Comment: I was thinking... If $b>0, ab=0 \implies (a+1)b=ab+b = b \implies (a+1)=1 \implies a=0$

Comment: If you add 1 to ab wouldn't you have (a+1)*b = 1?

Comment: I'm not adding 1 to $ab$, just to $a$, then using distributivity to find the result.

Comment: I thought it was by the associative law that you are allowed to do this? So ab = 0 ==> ab + 1 = 1 ==> a*(b+1) = 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's get there without using division.

We are given that $ab=0$

If $b>0$, we have 
$\begin{align}
(a+1)b&=ab+b \\
\text{but }\hspace{1in}ab&=0\\\implies (a+1)b&=b\\
\implies (a+1)&=1\\
\implies a&=0\\\end{align}$

and similarly $a>0 \implies b=0$

Therefore $ab=0 \implies a=0$ or $b=0$

Comment: Getting from $xy=y$ to $x=1$ would sure seem to require division. It's the same as saying the map $x\mapsto xy$ is injective - but that's the only non-trivial thing we'd have to prove to know that division is well-defined.

Comment: @Meelo - I used the fact that (a+1) turned out to be the multiplicative identity. That isn't division.

Comment: @Joffan I see that $x=1$ implies $xy=y$, but you used the converse. The converse is false in a ring - for instance $3\cdot 3\equiv 3 \pmod 6$, however we cannot conclude that $3=1$ from this. There are clearly some unstated assumptions when we make that leap. Indeed, at least when multiplication is commutative, I suspect this fact is sufficient to know that there is an extension of the ring to a field - i.e. a notion of division.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Cancellation Law states that given integers a, b, and c, such that c is non-zero and $ac=bc$, $a=b$. In this case we have $(a+1)b = b$ or $(a+1)b =(1)b$. We are assuming $b>0$, therefore this leads to $(a+1)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like your question needs some more context (what axioms you have to use, etc.), but I will try to provide an easy proof that uses minimal "sophistication":

**Problem:** If $ab=0$, then either $a=0$ or $b=0$.

*Proof.* Suppose $ab=0$ and, without loss of generality, that $a\neq 0$. Then $a^{-1}$ exists and
$$
b=1\cdot b = (a^{-1}\cdot a)b=a^{-1}(ab)=a^{-1}\cdot 0 = 0,
$$
as desired, showing that $b=0$ (simply assume $b\neq 0$ to get that $a=0$--this is what the "without loss of generality" covers).

---

My answer assumes some things about what you are able to assume. As I said, your question needs more context I feel to be effectively answered in full.